# Parallel.For causing static function non-null parameter to become null

Tags: c#, .net

I have a double for-loop that has no issues but is failing when I convert the outer loop into a Parallel.For ... it fails due to this function being called:

```
NormalizationPoint.CalculateDose( 
     fPixel1, fPixel2, uncompensatedBeams, new Vector3D( xLocation, yLocation, PlaneZ ) );
```

where the function has this signature:

```
 public static double CalculateDose(
    FluencePixel fluencePixel1, FluencePixel fluencePixel2, 
    Beam[] uncompensatedBeams, Vector3D location )
```

the fPixel1, which I'm certain is not null, is somehow becoming null in the body of CalculateEstimatedDose (which does not set it anywhere). Oddly, fPixel2 is being passed in just fine. Here is the full code:

```
Parallel.For(0, yLength, y =>
{
    for ( int x = 0; x < xLength; x++ )
    {
        double xLocation = ImageData.Origin.X + ( 0.5 + x ) * ImageData.XRes; // offset by half pixel to get center of pixel
        double yLocation = ImageData.Origin.Y + ( 0.5 + y ) * ImageData.YRes;
        Vector3D pixelLocation = new Vector3D( xLocation, yLocation, PlaneZ );
        if (( fPixel1 = fluences[0].GetIntersectingFluencePixel( pixelLocation ) ) != null
            && ( fPixel2 = fluences[1].GetIntersectingFluencePixel( pixelLocation ) ) != null )
        {
            // I added this redundant check just to be SURE it wasn't passed in null
            if ( fPixel1 == null || fPixel2 == null )
            {
                DosePlaneDirectBitmap.Bits[x + y * xLength] = ( alpha << 24 ) | 0x8B;
                continue;
            }

            // HERE IS THE PROBLEM SPOT, SOMEHOW CAUSING fPixel1 TO BECOME NULL IN THE FUNCTION 
            double doseValue = NormalizationPoint.CalculatedDose( fPixel1, fPixel2, uncompensatedBeams, new Vector3D( xLocation, yLocation, PlaneZ ) ) / NormalizationPoint.LastEstimatedDose;
            output[x, y] = doseValue;
        }
        else
        {
            //DosePlaneBitmap.SetPixel( x, y, Color.FromArgb(alpha, 0, 0, 0x8B)); // dark blue
            DosePlaneDirectBitmap.Bits[x + y * xLength] = ( alpha << 24 ) | 0x8B;
        }
    }
}
);
```

Again, simply replacing Parallel.For with

```
for ( int y = 0; y < yLength; y++ )
```

Does not result in that null-pointer exception inside the static CalculateDose function (which is not overloaded in any way).  Any ideas?

Comment: Is `NormalizationPoint.CalculatedDose` thread safe?

Comment: You said that the code never sets fPixel1.  Well, this statement does: `if (( fPixel1 = fluences[0].GetIntersectingFluencePixel( pixelLocation ) ) != null`.  Perhaps you should declare fPixel1 within the loop so that each thread will have its own copy.

Comment: John Wu, it seems you got it! - I needed to declare the variables inside the scope of the Parallel.For... Add an answer if you want and I can mark it as answered. Thanks a lot (it really sped things up in a speed-critical part of my application!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line will modify `fPixel1`:

```
if (( fPixel1 = fluences[0].GetIntersectingFluencePixel( pixelLocation ) ) != null
        && ( fPixel2 = fluences[1].GetIntersectingFluencePixel( pixelLocation ) ) != null )
```

Since `fPixel1` appears to be declared outside of the for loop, all the various threads can access it and it is possible some other thread has set it to null.

My suggestion is to declare `fPixel1` inside the for loop.  As a general rule, variables should be as tightly scoped as possible, so I actually would put it inside the inner loop:

```
Parallel.For(0, yLength, y =>
{
    for ( int x = 0; x < xLength; x++ )
    {
        double xLocation = ImageData.Origin.X + ( 0.5 + x ) * ImageData.XRes; // offset by half pixel to get center of pixel
        double yLocation = ImageData.Origin.Y + ( 0.5 + y ) * ImageData.YRes;
        Vector3D pixelLocation = new Vector3D( xLocation, yLocation, PlaneZ );
        FluencePixel fPixel1 = fluences[0].GetIntersectingFluencePixel( pixelLocation );
        FluencePixel fPixel2 = fluences[1].GetIntersectingFluencePixel( pixelLocation );

        if ( fPixel1 != null && fPixel2 != null)
        {
           //Etc.....
```

I also got rid of the "assignment inside if condition" since that is clearly a confusing construct.

Comment: Excellent John.